# Find directory getting specific file

Tags: r, directory

I want to find directory automatically which is placed with specific file in R.

For example, "/home/R_code/dataloading/abcd.R" is directory and file name.
How can I find "/home/R_code/dataloading" with the file names "abcd.R".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `basename` and `dirname` functions

```
path <- "/home/R_code/dataloading/abcd.R"
basename(path)
#[1] "abcd.R"

dirname(path)
#[1] "/home/R_code/dataloading"
```

---

If you do not know the actual path of the file and just know it's name. We could use `list.files` with `pattern`

```
file_path <- list.files("/home/R_code/", recursive = TRUE, pattern = "abcd.R")
dirname(file_path)
```

`file_path` would have the files in "/home/R_code/" directory which has "abcd.R" in their name. Now we can use `dirname` to get directory name of the files.

Comment: But, I couldn't know directory name. Just with my file name, I have to find directory..

Comment: @Daeun updated the answer. In the path just use some general path like  `/home/` or `/home/R_code/` where all the files are present under it and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick help! So powerful.